# Grails can you ensure a datasource connection is reused between calls in a request?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Problem: Using grails, SQL Server, and the DBAs want to use triggers for auditing user DB activity (I'm aware of the auditing plugins).  They suggested setting SQL Server's CONTEXT_INFO before each database call, setting the username in the context, which would then be pulled by the trigger.  What I'm considering is augmenting the GORM save et al. methods like this:

```
private replaceSave(domainClass) {

        def saveMethod = domainClass.metaClass.pickMethod("save", [Map] as Class[])

        domainClass.metaClass.save = { Map params ->
            def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
            sql.execute("DECLARE @U varbinary(0128);SET @U = CONVERT(varbinary(0128),'the-username');SET CONTEXT_INFO @U;")
            saveMethod.invoke(delegate, [params] as Object[])
            sql.execute("DECLARE @U varbinary(0128);SET @U = CONVERT(varbinary(0128),'');SET CONTEXT_INFO @U;")
        }
}
```

I don't know if this technique would ensure that the dataSource connection used by the saveMethod is the same connection used by the Sql object's connection.  My understanding is that Grails uses an OpenSessionInView pattern, which would seem to imply the same connection is reused, but I'm just guessing and having difficulty writing a thorough test for this.   Thanks!

Comment: See my edit, maybe now is better explained.